# enabling assertions in ant

Tags: java, ant, junit, assert, assertions

I want to enable the assertion facility in `ant`. In my ant `build.xml`, I put the follows, trying to enable assertions.

`<project> ...
<assertions>
<enable/>
</assertions>
</project>`

I put assertion in a `junit` file, which includes only one function,

```
testAssertions() {
  assert false;
}
```

when running `ant`, assertion fails are not thrown.. How to enable assertion in this setting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like your `<assertions>` subelement is a child of `<project>`, is this correct?

I am assuming that you are running the test via the `<junit>` ant task.  If this is correct, making the `<assertions><enable/></assertions>` subelement a child of `<junit>` should work.

Comment: this works! but it also print ``null`` along with the assertion error, which seems not right.

Comment: @Richard: What if you use, `assert false : "Error message goes here";`

Comment: Also note that `fork="true"` must be set in the `<junit>` element for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

To enable assertions, I edited `nbproject/project.properties` and changed

```
# Space-separated list of JVM arguments used when running the project.
# You may also define separate properties like run-sys-prop.name=value instead of -Dname=value.
# To set system properties for unit tests define test-sys-prop.name=value:
run.jvmargs=
```

to

```
run.jvmargs=\
    -ea
```

After doing this, assertions were enabled when I executed `ant run`.